# AdS space - Poincare Patch

Tags: ads-cft, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

How can I work out in detail the explicit coordinate transformation formulas needed to go from the "canonical" coordinates to the "Poincare patch"? I'm reading about AdS but the text takes the validity of the Poincare patch for granted, which troubles me. It only has a drawing showing the Poincare patch covering half the whole space, which doesn't help.

Comment: More on AdS: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36303/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend the article *Introduction to the Maldacena Conjecture on AdS/CFT,* [arXiv:hep-th/9902131](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9902131), by Petersen. I suspect that the first 8 pages would be helpful.