# An introductory resource for learning AdS space

Tags: specific-reference, differential-geometry, ads-cft, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

Can someone please point me to introductory resources about the geometry of Anti DeSitter Space ? What are some examples of other spaces used in theoretical physics ?.I'm learning Differential Geometry right now , I want to apply what I learn on simple spaces of importance in theoretical physics. Like , I want to investigate the nature of these spaces , calculate their metrics , curvature and other things.

Comment: Moschellas's "deSitter and Anti deSitter Sightseeing Tour" is pretty good available [here](http://www.bourbaphy.fr/moschella.pdf)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17093/2451

Comment: Thanks you , guys . Is it a good idea to try to apply things that I learn in differential geometry on spaces like Ads and others?

Comment: @EGY: It's necessary--- but AdS spaces are symmetric, so if you don't do calculations that take the symmetry into account, you are doing too much work.

Comment: Thanks , Ron . I know that I have to take symmetry into account . I have one more seemingly unrelated question , What are the topics in string theory that can be understood with only a mathematical background in topology,algebraic topology and analysis on manifolds? I have studied only very introductory topics in quantum field theory (Only the first four chapters in peskin)