# Understanding the AdS/CFT Correspondence

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, resource-recommendations, education, ads-cft

I am beginning to learn about the AdS/CFT correspondence, but I can't find a comprehensive introduction that includes the relevant gravitational/string theory physics. What specific areas of general relativity and superstring theory are essential for understanding the correspondence?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36303/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [these lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0689), which discuss many prerequisites for understanding the correspondence in a concise yet accessible way.

Answer (score 2):

Try [here](http://www-library.desy.de/preparch/desy/proc/proc02-02/Proceedings/pl.6/deboer_pr.pdf) for background into the derivation of the AdS/CFT correspondence and also [this thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.0856) for an excellent introduction to the correspondance with regards to symmetry breaking.

Further to this, try these [slides](http://www.sinap.ac.cn/qm2006/ppt/Nov.13/lectures-v2.pdf) outlining the motivations and also providing a good reading list.